# Python requests and beautifulsoup4, collecting only the "href" links

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, python-requests

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.brightscope.com/ratings"
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

data = soup.find_all('li',{"class":"more-data"})+soup.findAll('li', {"class":"more-data topten"})
for item in data:
   print(item('a'))
```

I would like to print only the hrefs but I cannot seem to figure this out. I've looked at different videos and can't get it. What am I doing wrong? I know the above code is printing the contents of the "a" tag but I need just the href's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to use the *dictionary-like access to element's attributes*:

```
[a['href'] for a in item('a')]
```

---

And, as a side note, you can improve the way you are locating your `li` elements, instead of:

```
data = soup.find_all('li',{"class":"more-data"})+soup.findAll('li', {"class":"more-data topten"})
for item in data:
   print(item('a'))
```

You can do:

```
links = soup.select("li.more-data a")
for a in links:
    print(a["href"])
```

where `li.more-data a` is a [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) which would match all `a` elements inside `li` elements with `more-data` class.